# Wait for save before continuing with the function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mongoose, synchronization

I have a loop which loops through an array of users, this loop is asynchronous, what I want to do is for every user create a new document and save it and wait for this to save and then move on to the next user. I am able to handle when to move on to the next user, so my problem is while saving the new document data. I am using mongoose save method.

The main function is running the loop, here is a sample.
**NOTE: 'async' is the async module v2.6.0**

```
async.forEach(users, (user, callback)=>{
    console.log(`Checking ${user.first_name}`);
    createNewDocument(user, (err)=>{
          if(!err) {
               console.log("New document created.");
               callback();
          }
    }, (err)=>{
        if(!err){
            console.log("All users were updated");
        }
    });
}
```

The non-async method

```
users.forEach((user)=>{
   console.log(`Checking ${user.first_name}`);
   createNewDocument(user, (err)=>{
        if(!err) {
               console.log("New document created.");
          }
   });
});
```

The createNewDocument function

```
function createNewDocument(user, callback)
{
      console.log("Creating a new doc...");
      let doc = new Doc();
      doc.save((err)=>{
         if(!err){
            console.log(`New doc created for user ${user.first_name}`);
            callback;
         }
      });
      console.log("Creating a new doc finished executing...");
}
```

Everything is executed and the last thing I get in my log is bunch of "New doc created for user...." for all the users.
I have tried quite a lot of stuff, I tried putting the doc.save in a promise but that didn't work as well, not sure what should I do now.

**EDIT: It's important for me to create the new document before moving on to the next user, I don't want to add them to calls array and then execute it, I need to make a check that the previous document actually exist and take some data from it on the next time the loop enters**

Comment: "what I want to do is for every user create a new document and save it and wait for this to save and then move on to the next user". Then why are you using an asynchronous loop? The entire point of async is NOT to wait.

Comment: I used non async loop previously and it lead to the same issue until someone suggested to use async and that was my exact point that async is not to wait, and they said the callback would control that.

Comment: "callbacks" have nothing to do with async behavior really. There are plenty of sync functions that use callbacks. The native `Array.forEach` uses one.

Comment: @gforce301 I have used it as well, I edited to post and included that function as well, you might want to take a look at it, it still leads to the exact same issue.

Comment: Well it appears that `doc.save` is also async which is why it is still happening.

Comment: @gforce301 That's exactly the problem. The whole issue is with doc.save. I am thinking of update everything on memory and then run 1 doc.save call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been promises for nested async and proper error handling for years already. Recently there are the `async` and `await` syntax to make promises look like C# code but the important thing is to learn how promises work because that syntax uses promises.

Using promises you can do the following:

```
const createNewDocument = user =>
  new Promise(
    (resolve,reject) => {
      console.log("Creating a new doc...");
      let doc = new Doc();
      doc.save(
        err=>{
          console.log("Creating a new doc finished executing...");
          err
            ? reject(err)
            : resolve(`New doc created for user ${user.first_name}`)
        }
      );      
    }
  );

const saveDocuments = (users,processedSoFar=[]) => {
  if(users.length===0){
    return processedSoFar;
  }
  console.log(`Checking ${users[0].first_name}`);
  return createNewDocument(users[0])
  .then(
    result=>{
      console.log("New document created.");
      processedSoFar.push(users[0]);
      return saveDocuments(users.slice(1),processedSoFar);      
    }
  )
  .catch(
    err=>Promise.reject([err,processedSoFar])
  );
}

saveDocuments(users)
.then(
  result=>{
    console.log("Processed the following users:",users);
  }
)
.catch(
  ([err,processed])=>{
    console.log(
      "Something went wrong:",err,
      "Processed so far:",processed
    )
  }
)
```